# Is webSocket.onopen in this example a callback? How does it work?

Tags: html, websocket, callback

I'll be brief. I'm trying to understand how **evt** is being passed to **webSocket.onopen**:

```
wsUri = 'ws://echo.websocket.org/';
webSocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

//How is evt actually passed?
webSocket.onopen = function (evt) { 
    onOpen(evt); 
}

function onOpen(evt) {
    writeOutput("CONNECTED");
}

function writeOutput(message) {
    var output = $('#divOutput');
    output.html(output.html() + '<br />' + message);
}
```

I've learned that I can accomplish the same thing with jQuery:

```
//This approach I get
$(webSocket).on('open', function(evt) { 
    onOpen(evt); 
})
```

To my understanding the two are callbacks. I've been primarily using callbacks like so:

```
function(callback) {
    callback();
}
```

The initial example doesn't seem that clear to me, maybe because I'm not that used to plain JavaScript, or there's something else I'm missing entirely.

Comment: In both cases you are assigning reference of your handler function to webSocket object. Both are doing the same thing of accepting the function reference so that the function can be called later when required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webSocket.onopen = function (evt) { 
    onOpen(evt); 
}
```

`evt` is passed by websocket. in above code you are setting a listener function on websocket on open. It means when websocket gets opened, the function assigned to `webSocket.onopen` will be called. just like onMessage or onClose. There is no actual need to write another `onOpen(evt)` , just do your stuff like this:

```
webSocket.onopen = function (evt) { 
    writeOutput("CONNECTED");
    //other codes
}
```

its almost similar to observer pattern. you can check observer pattern to see how is this exactly working internally. Briefly, in these type of examples, Its about assigning an method (function) to a reference to be called when something happens.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I needed to go back to JavaScript and play around to understand it, as opposed to only using callbacks in jQuery.

Comment: @AlexLuigi True. Also if my answer was solution to your problem, dont forget to mark it as right answer :D welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: I can't do that because my reputation is under 15, thus it's not taken into consideration by stackoverflow.

Comment: @AlexLuigi you certainly can and should mark the answer as accepted if it solved the issue (it's the check mark), and you can do that regardless of reputation. Upvoting is a different thing, that you might not be able to do.